# Magento 2: After uprgading magento version Order Items not adding from admin

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, sales-order

Create a new order from the Admin panel for a particular customer. Magento default functionality is not working

When I add a new product and update to the shopping cart option then the page refresh but the product does not add to the Item order.

There is no error in the console.

Logfile has below error:

```
Broken reference: the 'page.menu' tries to reorder itself towards 'header', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'content' respectively. [] []
```

[image]

Comment: Try to run the compile command one's and then check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same issue in magento 2.3.7-p1. In logs, it was showing this error:

```
main.WARNING: Session size of 370635 exceeded allowed session max size of 256000. [] []
```

To fix this, run below command:

```
php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0
```

After cache flush, I was able to add products to shopping cart from admin order create page.

Comment: Great Answer!! Worked like a charm :) Can you please explain it further ? So We can know what we exactly did?

Comment: Thanks for saving the time. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: Session size of 296272 exceeded allowed session max size of 256000.**

Solution: To run command

```
php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0
```

After do reindexing and flushing the cache.

```
php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hit given below command**

```
php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 512000
```

**and after that hit these commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
php bin/magento indexer:reindex;
php bin/magento c:f;
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/ var/
```

**I hope it is working for you.**

Answer (score 0):

its working thanks for the great solution

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/198493)